# How can I stop my Webkit browsers (except Chrom(ium/e) start LibreOffice and Acrobat when loading plugins?

Tags: 64-bit, browser, plugins, webkit

Recently I've found a problem with my webkit browsers (Midori, Liferea's browser tab/feed preview, etc). When loading plugins (which is on start up for Midori), Adobe Acrobat's splash screen pops up, followed by LibreOffice. I don't know what made it start happening but I think it happened after I (temporarily) installed flash player 32bit.

I would like this problem to go away as it can be rather annoying. What can I do?

Seems to have partly fixed itself, in that when you start the browser the plugins won't load automatically, but they still load (all of them) when you open just 1.

Comment: Roland - if you temporarily rename `~/.config/midori/extensions` to something else, does the midori issues still occur?

Comment: @fossfreedom: yeah, I don't think that folder is relevant. It doesn't have anything but form filler info and a blank addons file.

Comment: playing with flash will make you go blind....

Comment: @Allan: Eye ocean hot ewe bid lear...

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on Gentoo (both epiphany and midori) and I decided to just remove the Libreoffice plugin, but of course after an upgrade it does it again. Really annoying. At least you know it isn't really a Ubuntu issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the LibreOffice plugin ;-)

Comment: Almost there :). The Adobe plugin still starts when not needed.

Comment: I've accepted this answer, since Adobe Acrobat no longer starts when not wanted, and the LibreOffice plugin does nothing of use.